# How can I associate each array element with a function?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, delegates

I have an array and numbers stored in it:

```
int[] numbers = new int[5]  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

I have a method randomly pick up a number:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int r = rnd.Next(numbers.Length);
int Token = (numbers[r]);
```

I have each Token associated with a method:

```
if (Token == 1) 
{
    ThreadStart Ref1 = new ThreadStart(f.VehicleThread1);
    Thread Th1 = new Thread(Ref1);
    Th1.Start();
}
if (Token == 2)
{
    ThreadStart Ref2 = new ThreadStart(f.VehicleThread2);
    Thread Th2 = new Thread(Ref2);
    Th2.Start();
}
if (Token == 3)
{
    ThreadStart Ref3 = new ThreadStart(f.VehicleThread3);
    Thread Th3 = new Thread(Ref3);
    Th3.Start();
}
if (Token == 4)
{        
    ThreadStart Ref4 = new ThreadStart(f.VehicleThread4);
    Thread Th4 = new Thread(Ref4);
    Th4.Start();
}
if (Token == 5)
{
    ThreadStart Ref5 = new ThreadStart(f.VehicleThread5);                     
    Thread Th5 = new Thread(Ref5);
    Th5.Start();
}
```

But if I try aborting the thread outside this, it's generating an error message which is obvious.

```
if (Token == 1)
    list.RemoveAt(0);

numbers = list.ToArray(typeof(int)) as int[]; 
Th1.Abort();
```

Comment: Can't you just create an array of Func or Action in case you don't need the return value?

Answer (score 5):

You could just create an array of `ThreadStart` delegates instead:

```
ThreadStart[] delegates = new ThreadStart[5] 
{
    f.VehicleThread1, 
    f.VehicleThread2, 
    f.VehicleThread3, 
    f.VehicleThread4, 
    f.VehicleThread5 
};

Thread th = new Thread(delegates[Token - 1]); // -1 because array indexes start at 0
th.Start();
```

Or perhaps a `Dictionary<int, ThreadStart>`:

```
Dictionary<int, ThreadStart> delegates = new Dictionary<int, ThreadStart>() 
{
    { 1, f.VehicleThread1 }, 
    { 2, f.VehicleThread2 }, 
    { 3, f.VehicleThread3 }, 
    { 4, f.VehicleThread4 }, 
    { 5, f.VehicleThread5 }
};

Thread th = new Thread(delegates[Token]); // -1 not needed here
th.Start();
```